# EasyMock Void Methods mismatch of object hashcode

Tags: java, junit, mocking, easymock

I have create an mock object for HttpSession like below.

```
HttpSession mocks.createMock(HttpSession.class);
```

Now i am testing some method the method is

```
public String validateProduct(String productId,Model model,HttpServletRequest request){
    Customer customer=new Customer();
    Product product=customerService.validateProduct(productId, VSCConstants.CLIENT_CODE);
    customer.setProduct(product);
    /*Doing more operation with customer*/
    request.getSession().setAttribute(
            VSCConstants.SESSION_CUSTOMER,customer);
    request.setAttribute("response", "InValidVIN");
    return "forward:/profile";
}
```

Now my junit test code for that is

```
expect(customerService.validateProduct(null, VSCConstants.CLIENT_CODE))
            .andReturn(new Product());
expect(request.getSession()).andReturn(session).anyTimes();
    session.setAttribute(VSCConstants.SESSION_CUSTOMER, createdObject);
    expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Customer>() {
          public Customer answer() throws Throwable {
              createdObject= (Customer) EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()[1];
              return null;
          }
    });
```

Now the problem is as the `session.setAttribute()` method is void method so i have used
expectLastCall()  but if you see the method which I am testing is creating a new customer and adding that to the session so here it's getting mismatch and I am getting flowing exception.

```
Unexpected method call HttpSession.setAttribute("SESSION_CUSTOMER", com.budco.vsc.domain.Customer@feebefcb):
HttpSession.setAttribute("SESSION_CUSTOMER", null): expected: 1, actual: 0
at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
at $Proxy6.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
at com.budco.vsc.mvc.controller.AdvancedCustomerSearchController.validateProduct(AdvancedCustomerSearchController.java:110)
at com.budco.vsc.mvc.controller.AdvancedCustomerSearchController.getAdvancedSearchResult(AdvancedCustomerSearchController.java:83)
at com.budco.vsc.mvc.controller.AdvancedCustomerSearchControllerTest.testgetAdvancedSearchResultWithValidateProduct(AdvancedCustomerSearchControllerTest.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

show on .....

I hope , I need to use the same customer object which is use inside the test method but it's not possible as the method is creating the object.
Second option may be overriding the hashCode() but it will be heavy as the method doing lot of things on customer and it's a very big object contenting lot of other object and collections.
 Is there any easy way so that I simply skip the mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there I think (see below).  Here 1 is the parameter index in setAttribute for the Customer object you're trying to get a handle on.  Once you have it you should be able to compare the two Customer objects without any problems.

```
  private static Customer createdObject;


  expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Customer>() {
      public Customer answer() throws Throwable {
          createdObject = (Customer) EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()[1];
          return null;
      }
  });
```

Comment: session.setAttribute(VSCConstants.SESSION_CUSTOMER, createdObject);

This should be:
session.setAttribute(EasyMock.eq(VSCConstants.SESSION_CUSTOMER), EasyMock.anyObject(Customer.class));

You have no handle to the Customer object at that point, so you just expect any object of that type and then perform an assertion on the object later on, that it matches the one you expect it to (or whatever you'd prefer to assert on).

Comment: N.B. This 'later on' assertion is a JUnit one, not an EasyMock verification

Answer (score 1):

When testing servlet code, I personally would refrain from mocking requests, response and sessions with a mock framework and instead use dedicated `MockHttpServletRequest`, `MockHttpServletResponse` and `MockHttpSession` objects, all of which you can programmatically interact with.

Almost all major web frameworks have their version of these classes as you can see in [this JarFinder Search for `MockHttpSession`](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/search/~MockHttpSession~). Personally, I prefer the Spring mock components which are described [in the Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#mock-objects-servlet) and [in the package javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html).